# unable to filter UniqueId

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

This test

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('doclib1')/items?$select=ID,DocIcon,LinkFilename,Modified,Editor/Title,UniqueId,GUID&$expand=Editor
```

returns me

```
    {
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "b9c377f3-79cc-466a-b495-5834cff90ce0",
          "uri": "https://quantr.sharepoint.com/test/_api/Web/Lists(guid\u00275d9df756-8067-4599-b1cc-fc9ca610c4fe\u0027)/Items(1)",
          "etag": "\"1\"",
          "type": "SP.Data.Doclib1Item"
        },
        "Editor": {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "7980221b-5cff-4d10-8350-fed6b6f93894",
            "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
          },
          "Title": "wordpress"
        },
        "Id": 1,
        "ID": 1,
        "Modified": "2017-12-12T17:08:46Z",
        "UniqueId": "84ea42c1-abb4-466c-a7b4-532fbaf1515a",
        "LinkFilename": "大圍 !",
        "GUID": "f01e761d-0fd4-4d7d-a447-e3bd609bc821"
      },
    }
}
```

But this test `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('doclib1')/items?$select=ID,DocIcon,LinkFilename,Modified,Editor/Title,UniqueId,GUID&$expand=Editor&$filter=UniqueId+eq+guid%2784ea42c1-abb4-466c-a7b4-532fbaf1515a%27`

returns me empty json.

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": []
  }
}
```

If I filter by the GUID, it works again. Is it a bug? UniqueId is unable to be filter?

Comment: Tested in my Tenant environment, same issue, filter with UniqueId, not return anything, but filter with GUID, it works as expected, I found the same case has been posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074857/querying-a-list-item-through-uniqueid  I wonder this should be a problem with Rest API, you can create a feedback to report this issue:  https://office365.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it does not appear that `UniqueId` is supported as a refinable OData property at the moment. You can still filter by it by using a CAML-query however. Here's an example function that just outputs the result to the console (assumes you're using the classic experience):

```
function getByUniqueId(listTitle, uniqueId) { 
    var caml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId' /><Value Type='Guid'>"+uniqueId+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    var data = { "query" : {"__metadata": 
             { type: "SP.CamlQuery" }, ViewXml:caml}};

    var formDigest = document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value; 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("POST", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/GetItems", true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("accept","application/json;odata=verbose"); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/json;odata=verbose"); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-RequestDigest",formDigest); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) { 
            console.log(xhr.responseText);  
        }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter with Listitem Unique using the method `GetItemByUniqueId` in Rest API or CSOM. It works for both:

```
  /_api/web/lists(guid'7b754e56-9b3e-4fad-be8b-81e5c8aff350')/GetItemByUniqueId(guid'1b63edbc-12a7-4287-ad7d-f773aa8d2726')
```